# Magento 1.9 to 2 Migration : General error: 1419 You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled

Tags: mysql, migration, magento2, magento-1.9

I m migrating magento 1.9 to 2.x and when i try to migrate data using the migrate:data command it stops with the following error

> [Zend_Db_Statement_Exception]
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1419 You do not have the SUPER
>   privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the
>   less safe log_bin     _trust_function_creators variable), query was:
>   CREATE TRIGGER trg_catalog_compare_item_after_insert AFTER INSERT ON
>   catalog_compare_item FOR EACH ROW     BEGIN
>   INSERT INTO m2_cl_catalog_compare_item (`catalog_compare_item_id`,
>   `operation`) VALUES (NEW.catalog_compare_item_id, 'INSERT')ON
>   DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE      operation = 'INSERT';
>   END `

In my mysql server log_bin is set to off and i m using a super user. Can anyone help me to sort this out? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To resolve this, the value of the `log_bin_trust_function_creators` parameter as 1.
For more information [**log_bin_trust_function_creators**](https://techtavern.wordpress.com/2013/06/17/mysql-triggers-and-amazon-rds/)

one can execute below SQL:

```
mysql -u USERNAME -p
set global log_bin_trust_function_creators=1;
```

**Possible reason**: The latest gen of RDS MySQL has triggers disabled (while first gen apparently had it enabled default).